# grouped vm output to a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm looking for the best/simplest way to output the following using Razor (ASP.Net MVC 4)

```
         <ul id="contacts">
            <li data-group="a">
                <a class="title">A</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="thumbnail">
                                <img alt="" src="~/backendContent/sample/p4.jpg"></span> Adam Woodward
                                                            <span style="font-size: 11px; display: block;" class="muted">Creative Director</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="thumbnail">
                                <img alt="" src="~/backendContent/sample/p5.jpg"></span> Aileen Espinoza
                                                            <span style="font-size: 11px; display: block;" class="muted">Creative Director</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="thumbnail">
                                <img alt="" src="~/backendContent/sample/p6.jpg"></span> Aimee Foley
                                                            <span style="font-size: 11px; display: block;" class="muted">Creative Director</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-group="b">
                <a class="title">B</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="thumbnail">
                                <img alt="" src="~/backendContent/sample/p1.jpg"></span> Baker Terry
                                                            <span style="font-size: 11px; display: block;" class="muted">Creative Director</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>                        
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-group="c">
                <a class="title">C</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="thumbnail">
                                <img alt="" src="~/backendContent/sample/p1.jpg"></span> Cadman Mosley
                                                            <span style="font-size: 11px; display: block;" class="muted">Creative Director</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="thumbnail">
                                <img alt="" src="~/backendContent/sample/p2.jpg"></span> Cailin Jones
                                                            <span style="font-size: 11px; display: block;" class="muted">Creative Director</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>                        
                </ul>
            </li>
            .
            .
            .
```

as you can see its a contact list that will be formatted to a nice phonebook. I currently have a iqueryable that holds all the information in alphabetical order. I honestly was not sure on how to use razor to structure the above html. I thought about using a group function in linq and came up with the following linq expression:

```
        var _customers = (from c in _db.UserProfiles.Include("ParentCompanies").Include("cProfile")
                          where (c.ParentCompanies.Any(pc => pc.CompanyUsers.Any(cu => cu.UserName == userName)) && c.cProfile != null)
                         group c by c.FirstName.Substring(0, 1) into customerGroup
                         select new { FirstLetter = customerGroup.Key, Information = customerGroup }).OrderBy(letter=>letter.FirstLetter);
```

but I came across some problems with the return type of the method (anonymous type) and I was not sure how to deal with that. I am now using the following:

```
        var _customers = (from c in _db.UserProfiles.Include("ParentCompanies").Include("cProfile")
                          where (c.ParentCompanies.Any(pc => pc.CompanyUsers.Any(cu => cu.UserName == userName)) && c.cProfile != null)
                          select c).OrderBy(f=>f.FirstName);
```

I am  very new to the asp.net MVC world and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a custom return type for your query and use that as your view model.

```
public class GroupedCustomersViewModel
{
    string FirstLetter { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<UserProfile> Information { get; set; }
}

....

var _customers = 
    (from c in _db.UserProfiles.Include("ParentCompanies").Include("cProfile")
     where (c.ParentCompanies.Any(pc => pc.CompanyUsers.Any(cu => cu.UserName == userName)) && c.cProfile != null)
     group c by c.FirstName.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() into customerGroup
     select new GroupedCustomersViewModel
     {
         FirstLetter = customerGroup.Key, 
         Information = customerGroup 
     })
    .OrderBy(letter=>letter.FirstLetter);
```

In your `.cshtml` use

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Namespace.Models.GroupedCustomersViewModel>

...

<ul id="contacts">
    @foreach(var group in Model)
    {
    <li data-group="@group.FirstLetter.ToLower()">
        <a class="title">@group.FirstLetter</a>
        <ul>
            @foreach(var user in group.Information)
            {
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="thumbnail">
                        <img alt="" src="@user.Thumbnail"></span> @user.Name
                                                    <span style="font-size: 11px; display: block;" class="muted">@user.Title</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: wow, I like I said I'm very very new to this and that is just plain awesome!!!! -- Thanks

Comment: @hjavaher Notice that I added `.ToUpper()` inside the linq query. This should allow you to group "adams" and "Adams" under the same first letter.

Comment: Hey, When I try the code I keep getting the following error: `The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.` I've looked around and it seems like the way to fix it is to force the `_customers` into a list by `ToList()` I did that and it works except the fact that it doesn't include the `cProfile` in it. `cProfile` is just null.

Comment: actually nevermind, the `ToList()` doesn't have anything to do with it. its the grouping. I've taken out the grouping and its all there but as soon as I put it in its null.

Comment: @hjavaher not sure, but what if you do `new GroupedCustomersViewModel { FirstLetter = g.Key, Information = g.Include("ParentCompanies").Include("cProfile") }`?

Comment: there is no `Include` method for `customerGroup` :(